# Set Ng-model data with math

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I have a problem with AngularJS. In my form I have a couple of input's. I have to do some math with the data, and then save it. But because I use Angularfire I have to assign the result to a ng-model, and that's where i'm stuck. How can i do this?

Here's my code:

```
<label>First</label>
  <input name="firstmatch" ng-model="project.firstmatch">

  <label>Second</label>
  <input name="secondmatch" ng-model="project.secondmatch">

  <label>Third</label>
  <input name="thirdmatch" ng-model="project.thirdmatch">

  <label>Fourth</label>
  <input name="fourth" ng-model="project.fourthmatch">

  <label>Fifth</label>
  <input name="fifthmatch" ng-model="project.fifthmatch">

   <!-- The math part-->
 <textarea name="points" ng-model="project.points">   {{ project.firstmatch--project.secondmatch--project.thirdmatch--project.fourthmatch--project.fifthmatch }}   </textarea>
```

Thanks!

Comment: And yes, the math part looks crazy, but outputs the necessary data.

Comment: And Where are you assiging

Comment: I tried a lot of ways, this is one:  <textarea name="points" ng-model="project.points">   {{ project.firstmatch--project.secondmatch--project.thirdmatch--project.fourthmatch--project.fifthmatch }}   </textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you print the result in a textarea? Textareas don't accept code by default. Just try printing the result in a div or span.

If you by any means want the result to be editable then print it in another input and don't do the calculation inside it. Do the logic in the controller, like this:

```
<label>First</label>
    <input name="firstmatch" ng-model="project.firstmatch">

<label>Second</label>
  <input name="secondmatch" ng-model="project.secondmatch">

<label>Third</label>
  <input name="thirdmatch" ng-model="project.thirdmatch">

<label>Fourth</label>
  <input name="fourth" ng-model="project.fourthmatch">

<label>Fifth</label>
  <input name="fifthmatch" ng-model="project.fifthmatch">

<!-- The math part-->
<input type="text" name="points" ng-model="project.points" />
```

And than in the controller write:

```
$scope.project.points = $scope.project.firstmatch - $scope.project.secondmatch - $scope.project.thirdmatch - $scope.project.fourthmatch - $scope.project.fifthmatch;
```